# Proof regarding GCD

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to prove that if $a,b$ are two primes between themselves then $a+b$ and $a^2+ab+b^2$ are also prime between themselves.

That is, we have to prove that  $\text{gcd}(a,b)=1\Rightarrow \text{gcd}(a+b,a^2+ab+b^2)=1$ .

Should I try Bezout ? Any hint on what should I proceed on doing ?

Comment: @nerdy: 
The usual word is "$a,b$ coprime". Then the simplest method, IMO, is probably just using the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: It was incorrectly edited again, and this time it was not me ._.

Comment: Mhenni, I rolled back because the original question said $a^2 + ab + b^2$. Agent154 did a wrong edit.

Comment: I edited based on another edit.

Comment: Ok, we need to correct this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Notice that $p\mid a+b$ and $p\mid a^2 + ab + b^2$ together imply $p$ divides
$$
a^2 = a^2+ab+b^2 - b(a+b)
$$
and
$$
b^2 = a^2+ab+b^2 - a(a+b).
$$

Comment: Quite so - and I was just preparing a similar answer when agent154 falsified the mathematics in the original question.

Comment: @RobArthan Bah. Sorry for stealing your thunder then. Bad timing!

Comment: @RobArthan And as am I... I thought I was being helpful with my first edit... *sigh*

Comment: Hm, so that shows that a+b and a² + ab + b²  have the same common divisors as a and b and hence the same gcd. And with the same gcd we can conclude the implicationwhich is equivalent to gcd(a,b) = gcd(a+b, a² + ab + b²) = 1.
Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Exactly. Happy to help! `: )`